# Breeding herd of cattle in the pasture

Tags: writing

It is correct to use: breeding herd of cattle in the pasture.

Comment: What exactly causes your suspicion that this sentence might be correct or incorrect? Proofreading questions are off-topic on this site. You might also want to consider posting your question to 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) - just make sure to expand it to show what exactly you do not understand in the sentence.

Comment: So is the herd of cattle breeding in the pasture?  I've seen cattle grazing in the pasture and I've heard of "breeding cattle" or "raising cattle" but not "breeding cattle in the pasture".  It does not sound right to my native ear.

Comment: The way I read it, it's not a sentence. There's no verb. "Breeding herd" is telling you what kind of herd it is.

Comment: If the intention is to describe that there is a herd of cattle in the pasture that is used for breeding purposes then "herd of breeding cattle in the pasture" would surely be better? It is the cattle that do the breeding individually, not the group.

Comment: @MarvMills But (a) "breeding herd" *is* a phrase used in farming to describe such a herd. So the phrase in the OP could be correctly used in something like "my breeding herd of cattle in the pasture is bigger than the other herd that's currently in the barn".

Comment: @Rupe Ah right, fair enough, I did not know that... It still sounds odd to non-farming ears though. Perhaps it's a specialised term and not in general usage?

Comment: I think "suckling herd" is more common, but not sure if it means exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term used to refer to a cow that is kept for breeding purposes is ***brood cow***. Therefore, it would be better to say, "*herd of brood cows in the pasture*."

> 2 brood  adjective
>
> Definition of BROOD
>
> :  kept for breeding

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brood

Comment: I think if you google "breeding herd" you find enough documents to suggest it's a term that can be used for such a herd.